# How to represent this superscript?

Tags: errors, superscripts

I am trying to write this command below but it doesnt work.

```
$$\triangle$^m$
```

Comment: This question got bumped due to an edit to one of the answers.  Before voting it down, please read http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/maintaining-a-balance/

Comment: To address the OP’s apparent misconception:

You may have been told to write `$\triangle$` to get the △ shape, but that’s because you need to be in “math mode” to use the `\triangle` command. A single `$` puts you into math mode, where you can use both the `\triangle` command and the superscript operator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have additional `$` signs in your code snippet. The superscript `^`, and subscript `_` need to be in math mode.

Use `$\triangle^m$` for superscript. If you want a subscript use `$\triangle_m$`.
If you intention is to make the entire term a sub- or superscript then you'll need to enclose it with a `{}` group.

[image]

### Note:

- For the superscript version, I think it looks better if you slightly move the superscript to the left via a `\kern`.
- If your intent is to use display math you should use `\[` and `\]` instead of `$$` delimiters. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Inline math: $\triangle^m \quad \triangle_m$
%
\[ \text{Display math:}\quad \triangle^m \quad \triangle_m \]
%
If the entire term is to be super or sub script:
\[ \text{Display math:}\quad x_{\triangle^m} \quad x_{\triangle_m} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to produce an dollar sign followed by a triangle followed by a dollar sign followed by a superscript `m`, the correct syntax is `$\$\triangle\$^m$`.
- If you want to produce a subscript triangle and a superscript `m`, the correct syntax is `${}_\triangle^m$`.