# How to bring equation into the middle of the line

Tags: formatting

I am trying to put this below equation in latex and also I need it in the middle of the line.

```
PPV =TP /(TP + FP)
```

Comment: Did you read Peter Grill's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70755/10679) to your previous question?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Do you want to make that an answer as display math will indeed center the equation.  For readability I would define `\newcommand*{\PPV}{\mathrm{PPV}}` and two more for `\TP`, and `\FP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about having those parameters in `\mathrm` as the nature of those functions are not known to me. However, the equation can be centered to a line as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %% added to show frames.
\newcommand*{\PPV}{\mathrm{PPV}}
\newcommand*{\TP}{\mathrm{TP}}
\newcommand*{\FP}{\mathrm{FP}}
\begin{document}
This is a line of text just for reference to know that the equation below is at the center of the line.
\[\PPV = \TP / (\TP + \FP)\]
\[\PPV = \frac{\TP}{(\TP + \FP)}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]